# Binding switch value to list element by index

Tags: xaml, xamarin, data-binding, xamarin.forms, binding

I have a multiple switch's (days of week) that I want to bind it to a list specific index's .. like Saturday => mylist[0] , Sunday mylist[1]
right now when i try to get the value it's return null !

My ViewModel

```
  private List<bool> _days;

  public List<bool> Days
    {
        get => _days;
        set
        {
            if (Equals(value, _days)) return;
            _days = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

My view

```
<Switch IsToggled="{Binding Days[0]}" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0"
                Scale="1.5" x:Name="SaturdaySwitch"></Switch>
 <Switch IsToggled="{Binding Days[1]}" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0"
                Scale="1.5" x:Name="SundaySwitch"></Switch>
```

Comment: Do you initialise the list somewhere? Because with just this code your list will always be null

Comment: Where should I initialize the list and should I give it a default size of 6 or that is flexible ?

Comment: If you just have this fixed list of 6 values, then I would keep it fixed, yes

Comment: Should I initialize it in the ViewModel ?

Comment: Depends on how you have tied thing together, but sounds like a great idea!

Comment: Dunno if you are applying SOLID, but if I were you I'd create a class called "YourViewModelInitializer" where you define an public "Initialize" method. Then you can call it where you create the VM. Just a clean code tip :)

Comment: I tried to create a constructor in my viewmodel and initialize the list .. now I get a (An unhandled exception occured.Unhandled Exception:
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation) ....... is this has some thing to do with OnPropertyChanged() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show you how in code, I created this quick-and-dirty sample for you which can be found here: https://github.com/jfversluis/FixedArraySample

In the ViewModel (here named PageModel), I define a List which is initialized with 7 values.

```
public List<bool> Days { get; set; } = new List<bool>
{
    false,
    false,
    true,
    false,
    false,
    false,
    true
};
```

Then in the page, I bind it like this:

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Label Text="Monday" />
    <Switch IsToggled="{Binding Days[0]}" />
</StackLayout>
```

This results in the screen below.
[image: Databound Switch controls]

To set the values back in the list when you toggle the switches as well, you probably want to add two-way data-binding, like: `<Switch IsToggled="{Binding Days[0], Mode=TwoWay}" />`.

Now the values will be updated in the `Days` list accordingly and you can access them in your ViewModel.